# ZK iterate through list of lists

Tags: java, listbox, zk, groupbox, zul

I'm totally new to the ZK framework and I'm not sure if the information I've provided would be enough or not.

I'm aware that, if there is a fixed number of categories, then in the `.zul` file - for each `Groupbox`, a `Listbox` can be displayed.

Currently, I have a list of users being displayed categorically i.e there is a dynamic number categories and each category has dynamic number of users. This is being implemented and displayed using `Vlayout`.

There is a requirement where if there are more than 10 users in each category, then we should display 10 users and then provide a button (or something similar) to display more users in the same category.

My questions are-

1. Is it possible to achieve this requirement using `Vlayout`?
2. If not, can we iterate through a list of `Groupbox`s to display `Listbox` (list of users) for
   each `Groupbox` (category) in the `.zul` file?
3. Or is there a simpler / more efficient way of achieving this
   requirement?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can refer to this [article](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2015/February/ZK8_Series:_UI_Template_Injection) to use "ForEach" and "If" tag to do so with Vlayout or Listbox.

For example,

```
<template name="tree">
    <forEach items="@load(vm.authors)" end="10" var="author">
        <vlayout>
            // omitted
        </vlayout>
    </forEach>
    <if test="@load(not empty vm.authors and vm.authors.size() gt 10)">
        <span>More...</span>
    </if>
</template>
```